# How to create a custom Pane for use in SceneBuilder where controls layout correctly

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am trying to provide some default behavior to a standard Pane in Java FX.  I would like to use this Pane in SceneBuilder.  For some reason the layout isn't working as I would expect.

I created the following component:

```
public class GroupBox extends Pane {
    public void configureGroupBox(String title) {
           //Perform needed set up here.....
    }
}
```

I have exported this control into a JAR file and imported that control into SceneBuilder.  I am able to select this control in SceneBuilder and add it to my FXML.

However, the problem starts when I attempt to add controls within it.  Even though this extends a javafx.scene.layout.Pane the layout engine of SceneBuilder is pushing all controls to the top left and overlapping them, rather than having no layout instructions.

Is what I am trying to do possible?  If so, is there something else I need to do?  At this point, my control is just an empty extension of the Pane class.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason for scene builder's behavior is that Pane (and your simple extension of this class) acts the same as you describe: You should set translate x/y for any node you put on the pane to move the node into your desired point. This is Pane's layout behavior for its children. What's your layout requirement for the GroupBox? Maybe you should extend some other javafx pane such as StackPane, BorderPane, etc which fits your needs.

Comment: The behavior should be for the controls placed in the group box to be dragged to it final position. Once set - it should stay there.

Comment: I have the same problem with a custom pane that extends AnchorPane. Seems the answer from Eric Le Ponner explains why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Scene Builder limitation.

SB provides full operation for builtin containers only (i.e. the ones that are part of JavaFX). For custom containers, it provides limited operations: typically SB allows to drop a component inside but not to move it (because it considers that extending Pane does not imply free positioning of children).

Comment: So then there is nothing I can do on this then?

Comment: I did notice that I can use the layout x & y properties in SceneBuilder to accomplish my goals....  So this is possible manually - so hopefully there is a way with WYSIWYG

Comment: Best not to bother with Scene Builder or FXML at all.  Just code your screens by hand.  It's just as fast and easy, and easier to maintain later on.

Comment: Sometimes the "fast and easy to maintain" code feels a bit obtrusive. So I personally like to have it in FXML.  @purring pigeon: may be you could first check if you really need to subclass Pane ; in many cases, composing (in place of subclassing) works very well.